# Service Stack - Trying to create a POST function and read the JSON data

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm just trying to create a simple POST function that let's me POST a JSON.  I've tried to copy examples but I'm not sure what I'm doing differently.  Any help would be appreciated, I feel like it's something simple that I'm missing.

What I'm trying to post:

POST Address: http://localhost:49653/save/file

Headers:
Content-Type: application/json

Raw Body:
{
  uuid: "someUuid",
  fileName: "test",
  dateTime: "dateee",
  json: "some json"
}

```
namespace SomeNamespace.Model
{
    [Route("/save/file", "POST")]
    public class SaveFileRequest
    {
        public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    }

    public class SaveFileResponse
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace SomeNamespace.ServiceInterface
{
    [EnableCors(allowedMethods:"POST")]
    public class SaveFileService : Service
    {
        public object Any(SaveFileRequest request)
        {
            var response = new SaveFileResponse { Success = false };
            string savedataJson;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                savedataJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(savedataJson);  // When I debug, the contents are ""
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {...}
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SaveFileRequest` Request DTO needs to implement `IRequiresRequestStream`.

Here are the docs for [reading directly from the request stream](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream):

#### Reading directly from the Request Stream

Instead of registering a custom binder you can skip the serialization of the request DTO, you can add the [IRequiresRequestStream](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IRequiresRequestStream.cs) interface to directly retrieve the stream without populating the request DTO.

```cs
//Request DTO
public class RawBytes : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The raw Http Request Input Stream
    /// </summary>
    Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

Which tells ServiceStack to skip trying to deserialize the request so you can read in the raw HTTP Request body yourself, e.g:

```cs
public object Post(RawBytes request)
{
    byte[] bytes = request.RequestStream.ReadFully();
    string text = bytes.FromUtf8Bytes(); //if text was sent
}
```

Comment: it worked thank goodness i've been on this for forever thank you!